# How can I extract a substring after a match position?

Tags: regex, string

I have a requirement to grep a string or pattern (say around 200 characters before and after the string or pattern) from an extremely long line ed file. The file contains streams of data (market trading data)  coming from a remote server and getting appended onto this line of the file.

I know that I can match lines containing a specific pattern using `grep` (or other tools), but once I have such lines, how can I extract a portion of the line? I want to grab the part of the line with the pattern plus roughly 200 characters before and after the pattern. I would be especially interested in answers using...(supply tools or languages you're comfortable with here).

Comment: So what is your problem, exactly?

Comment: Telling us your requirement and listing a whole ot of potential tools (?) is not even remotely a question. What does the data look like? What does the pattern look like? What have you tried?

Comment: Need to grep a string (say "ASDF" ) from the line as well as its surroundings. Hope I clarified the question.

Comment: @Jtk: you really haven't. `grep 'ASDF' filename` should work given what you say. What do you mean by "from the line as well as its surroundings"? Do you mean that the string has to appear in a line as well as somewhere else (? near the line? before? after?) in order for it to be a hit? Honestly, this is just silly.

Comment: My apologies for presenting it again with the word surroundings. In fact "ASDF" is exactly occur only once in the long line and the requirement is to collect the 200 characters before and after this string ("ASDF"). Since I ask this question because grep (together with xargs) offer the complete line as expected which is not what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @Jtk: ok, that actually helps. I stuck a suggested edit into your post above. Please edit that as you see fit, but I think that it (or something like it) would make the question a good deal clearer.

Comment: Thanks Telemachus for your help and appreciate it. The question I presented initially was inadequate since people who read it may not necessarily get the context exactly. Seems like the pattern matching /.{200}ASDF.{200}/ and will check it out. Regards.

Answer (score 6):

If what you need is the 200 characters before and after the expression plus the expression itself, then you are looking at:

```
/.{200}aaa.{200}/
```

If you need captures for each (allowing you to extract each part as a unit), then you use this regexp:

```
/(.{200})(aaa)(.{200})/
```

Answer (score 4):

If your `grep` has `-o` then that will output only the matched part.

```
 echo "abc def ghi jkl mno pqr" | egrep -o ".{4}ghi.{4}"
```

produces:

```
def ghi jkl
```

Answer (score 1):

`(.{0,200}(pattern).{0,200})`, or something?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want (in C)?
If it is, feel free to adapt to your specific needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void prt_grep(const char *haystack, const char *needle, int padding) {
  char *ptr, *start, *finish;
  ptr = strstr(haystack, needle);
  if (!ptr) return;
  start = (ptr - padding);
  if (start < haystack) start = haystack;
  finish = ptr + strlen(needle) + padding;
  if (finish > haystack + strlen(haystack)) finish = haystack + strlen(haystack);
  for (ptr = start; ptr < finish; ptr++) putchar(*ptr);
}

int main(void) {
  const char *longline = "123456789 ASDF 123456789";
  const char *pattern = "ASDF";

  prt_grep(longline, pattern, 5); /* you want 200 */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My Congratulations , you have just reinvented the wheel!

Comment: Is there a function to do this in the Standard C Library? In POSIX C library? If there is, best option is to ignore my answer and use the solution provided by the Library. [perl] [bash] [python] [php] [c] is an awful lot of language tags

Answer (score 0):

I think I might approach the problem by matching the part of the string I need, then using the match position as the starting point for the substring extraction. In Perl, once your regex suceeds, the `pos` built-in tells you where you left off:

```
 if( $long_string = m/$regex/ ) {
      $substring = substr( $long_string, pos( $long_string ), 200 );
      }
```

I tend to write my programs in Perl instead of doing everything in the regular expression. There's nothing particularly special about Perl in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be more basic that everybody is thinking, correct me if I'm wrong...
Do you want to print **before** and **after** the string **excluding** the string?

```
awk -F "ASDF" '{print "Before ASDF" $1 "\n" "After ASDF" $2}' $FILE
```

This will print something like:

> Before ASDF blablabla
>
> After ASDF blablablabla

Change it to match your needs, remove the "\n" and or the "Before..." and "After..." comments

Do you want to **supress** the string from the file?
This will replace the string with a blank space, again, change it to whatever you need.

```
sed -i 's/ASDF/\ /' longstring.txt
```

HTH